# What are the values that can be assigned to variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In all programming languages "variables" can be defined as follows :

"They are reserved places in RAM to store data"

Turns out that such code is logical in javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("IdName");
x.innerHTML = "Hello Stack Overflow";
```

Or This Code:

```
var x = alert("Hello Stack Overflow");
```

I don't get it, Of course `alert()` and `document.getElementById("")`

aren't data to be assigned to variables

I want someone to explain why such thing is possible.

I'm really confused of this.

Comment: Function calls do return data values.

Comment: Do you know other programming languages where you are familiar with the value/variable distinction?

Comment: Who says document.getElementById does not return data and you use the variable `x` to set the innerHTML? First line in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById): "Returns a reference to the element by its ID;"

Comment: What else would you do with `document.getElementById("IdName")` if you couldn't assign its return value to a variable…?

Answer (score 1):

No, `document.getElementById("IdName")` *"isn't"* data; it's a *function call* that **returns data**:

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID [...]
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> element = document.getElementById(id);
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> `id`
>   is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the
>   element being sought.
>
> ### Return Value
>
> `element`
>   is a reference to an `Element` object, or null if an element with the
>   specified ID is not in the document.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

The function call returns an object of type `Element` (or `null`), which is <del>data</del> a value that can be assigned to a variable. This works pretty much exactly the same in virtually all programming languages. Values can be assigned to variables. Functions return values.

[`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) does *not* happen to return anything, which means it implicitly returns `undefined`, so the value `undefined` will be assigned to `x`. That is a rather *useless* operation, but still works by the same rules.

Comment: Sorry if I got it wrong, but does that mean that document.getElementById() is a built-in function while the id name written in brackets is the parameter passed to it?

Comment: Yes, that's what a function call is: `foo(bar)` → `foo` is the function name, `bar` is a value passed to it as argument.